# How to disable requesting AAAA records when I have no IPv6 address?

Tags: scientific-linux, ipv6

Why can I see `AAAA` DNS requests when I run `tcpdump` on my Scientific Linux PC when I haven't got any IPv6 addresses? I already rebooted after setting `NETWORKING_IPV6=no` in `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `options ipv6 disable=1` in `/etc/modprobe.d/ipv6.conf`, but I can still see `AAAA` requests if I visit a few websites. How can I disable the requesting of `AAAA` records?

Comment: `options ipv6 off` and then in super shell run `modprobe -r ipv6`

Comment: If you have an IPv4 address, you automatically have a [6to4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4) IPv6 address, through which you may be able to reach IPv6 hosts (depending on what IPv6 connectivity your ISP offers).

Comment: Have you removed ::1 and other ipv6 addresses from your `/etc/hosts?`

Comment: Firefox has additionally the option to disable IPV6: go to about:config then change network.dns.disableIPv6

Comment: As per http://serverfault.com/questions/632665/how-to-disable-aaaa-lookups, there seems to be no easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Check if file /etc/resolv.conf has "options inet6".  If so, that line should be removed using your favorite editor (invoked via sudo or as root, after making a backup copy).  If you are using DHCP, it may get put back in the next time you reboot even if you have no IPv6 in your kernel network stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the following option to the kernel, on the Grub stage:

```
modprobe.blacklist=modname1
```

Where `modname` is the module name of ipv6 on Scientific Linux (probably `ipv6`)